# ankhsvn: access repository with username, password

Tags: visual-studio-2008, permissions, ankhsvn

From visual studio, I can see the repository on another system using the url:
svn://(ipaddress)/

But I am not able to write to the repository from my system. How can I access the repository with permissions from visual studio - ankhsvn (using Harry/Sally/custom_created username and password)? The error I see now is: "You failed to authorize against the remote repository" Both the systems are on LAN and we are not usig any domain setup. The subversion repository is on a windows Xp machine. I am trying to access it from a windows 7 machine.
I am new to subversion and ankhsvn. I do not know how to use subversion withouth the gui provided by ankhsvn. I used Collabnet's installer for subversion

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that usernames are case sensitive too? It's a common mistake to assume that the username case doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the user account you are specifying has permissions on the subversion repository.

I had the same problem and the cause ended up being that I had created a new repository on the server for testing and forgot to configure the server to use the global password file used by the other repositories.

Answer (score -1):

Opinion: if you are new to SVN, you'd rather use TortoiseSVN rather than Ankh. The integration with visual studio is nice, but it is not that important for the typical working style with SVN.